# Inheritance from other XML schema: redefining a single Type without touching the base xsd

Tags: xml, inheritance

I have an XML schema online that I want to extend. It looks similar like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="urn:inheritance:1"
           xmlns="urn:inheritance:1"
>

    <xs:complexType name="aType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="b" type="bType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="bType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="c"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Of which I would like to extend the type `bType`

My current solution is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="urn:inheritance:2"
           xmlns="urn:inheritance:2"
           xmlns:inh="urn:inheritance:1"
>

    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="urn:inheritance:1">

        <xs:complexType name="aType">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="aType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="b" type="bType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:complexType name="bType">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="bType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="newC" type="newCType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>

    </xs:redefine>

    <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="newCType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Which I find incredibly cumbersome and doesn't actually completely solve my problem as I have to repeat this structure if `bType` is used somewhere completely else.

Is it possible to do something like this, where I just redefine the type such that my original scheme is updated with this updated type:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="urn:inheritance:2"
           xmlns="urn:inheritance:2"
           xmlns:inh="urn:inheritance:1"
>

    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="urn:inheritance:1">

        <xs:complexType name="bType">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="bType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="newC" type="newCType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>

    </xs:redefine>

    <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="newCType"/>

</xs:schema>
```